# JPA domain mapping for table self join same table

Tags: java, spring, jpa

We have two id's/columns in same table....one is Event ID and another Event Series ID.. Both are actually same. It is like Event series is on top of Event with same data/ columns. It is like self join.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = Event)
public class Event {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = generation type.sequence, generator=entity_gen)
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne(FetchType = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "SER_ID")
  private Event event;
}
```

How to write domain object/ pojo class for this table ?
What I have written is correct or wrong.. Do this mapping have any drawbacks ??

After edit

I am using JPA, Spring MVC.

Comment: Ask different questions separately.  On your first question, your class design is fine.  What exactly is the first question?  The second question is unclear so when you move it to a new question, make sure to be clear about what you want to achieve.  May be some sample table data, a SQL query and expected result will help others understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: Be careful with the `equals()` and `hashcode()` functions. Infinite loops, infinite loops everywhere...

Comment: I'll keep that in check.. Thanks